# python поиск совпадений по массиву строк

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно найти наилучшее совпадение в массиве строк по запросу. 
Я не нашел какой-то библиотеки на эту тему, а велосипед создавать не очень хочется.

Comment: ["Как задать хороший вопрос?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), ["Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть у библиотеки difflib метод [difflib.get_close_matches](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches). Если я правильно понял вопрос, то он то, что нужно:

```
import difflib

heap = ['смыло', 'соло', 'вяло', 'мяло', 'смола', 'поле', 'воля', 'с мола', 'была', 
'стела', 'с мела','смело']
search = 'смело'

print(difflib.get_close_matches(search, heap, cutoff=0.6))
print(difflib.get_close_matches(search, heap, cutoff=0.8))
```

Получим:

```
['смело', 'смыло', 'с мела']
['смело', 'смыло']
```

Comment: Да. То, что ну нужно. Спасибо